# Clearing a vector of raw pointers to objects owned by unique pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, vector, smart-pointers

I am wondering what the best way is to clear a `vector` of `vector`s of raw pointers that point to objects owned by `unique_ptr`s without any memory leaks.

To make this more concrete, suppose that I have:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Person>> people;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Animal>> animals;
std::vector<std::vector<Animal*>> animalOwnerships;
```

I know I can use `people.clear()` and `animals.clear()`, which will delete the unique pointers to the class objects, which in turn will delete the class objects themselves (please correct me if I'm mistaken here).

If I call these first, then does `animalOwnerships` consist of dangling pointers? Is it okay to call `animalOwnerships.clear()` at this point without needing to worry about any memory leaks, or should it be called first, before the other two?

Also, do the individual `vectors` in `animalOwnerships` need to be cleared individually?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking. If you aren't sure which of `animalOwnerships` or `animals` will be destroyed first, perhaps you need shared ownership with `shared_ptr`? If they are being cleared at (nearly) the same time, it doesn't really matter in which order you clear them. It's fine to `clear` a vector of dangling pointers. Some people may appreciate the tidiness of clearing `animalOwnerships` first.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux In general, `animals` is permanent. There is only a single scenario in which I will be "resetting" these `vectors`, and I have complete control over the order in which I do it. Given this, should I call `animalOwnerships.clear()` before `animals.clear()`? Does it really matter, if I'm clearing them both consecutively? I am more curious about what is happening (in terms of pointers and memory) if I do call `animals.clear()` first.

Comment: When you clear `animals` you will destroy each `unique_ptr` it contains. This, in turn, `delete` each pointed `Animal` instance. At that point, `animalOwnerships` is unchanged, but it's pointers are all invalid (dangling). You can still destroy those pointers (not to be confused with giving them to `delete`) so it's not a problem to `clear` `animalOwnerships`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thank you for the explanation. Also, just to make sure I understand, it is okay to `clear` `animalOwnerships` first because the `Animal` objects/instances pointed to by the raw pointers in `animalOwnerships` are owned by `unique_ptr`s. If, instead, there were *no* `unique_ptr`s to those objects, and then I called `animalOwnerships.clear()`, then I would have a memory leak, as I would have then deleted the only pointers to the objects in memory. But, thanks to the `unique_ptr`s, I do not have to worry about that anymore. Is that correct?

Comment: Right. If you only had raw pointers, you would need to `delete` the `Animal` instances yourself before you clear the last vector.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks! That was pretty much everything I was wondering. If you would like to write an answer regarding these points, I can go ahead and accept it; otherwise, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointers are like pieces of paper with locations listed on them.

A dangling pointer is an address to a house that doesn't exist.

A memory leak occurs when the only record you have of the house is on a particular piece of paper, and you destroy it and lose track of the house.

A dangling pointer is untidy and risky in that if anyone follows it bad things happen, but it is not an immediate bug.  Even a leak isn't an immediate bug.

A unique ptr object is that same address -- same writing -- but written on a magic gem.  When the gem is destroyed, the house is destroyed too.

This makes it difficult to leak the resource without leaking the unique ptr.  And because the owner of the resource is clear -- it is that unique ptr -- it makes that unique ptr less likely to dangle, as everyone should know only to clean up the resource (destroy the house) by destroying the unique ptr (shattering the gem).

So clearing the people/animal vectors destroys the unique ptrs (the gems), which automatically destroys the houses (people and animals).

The vector-of-vector-of-pointers remains, but is full of dangling pointers.  It then becomes a good idea to clear it.  But there is no immediate harm from it existing.  Clearing it before, or afterwards, has no impact on the lifetime of the the people or animals, because it is just a set of notes that say where animals are in a structured table.

Comment: I felt like I was reading a fairy tale, what with the magic gems and all! But very clearly stated -- thank you!